# Remove tooltip hover effect on 'axis' trigger

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a stacked EChart graph with light area colors and a tooltip trigger set to 'axis':

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'));

option = {
  tooltip: { trigger: 'axis', },
  legend: { data: ['A', 'B', 'C'] },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  },
  yAxis: { type: 'value' },
  series: [ {
      name: 'C',
      type: 'line',
      areaStyle: { color: '#fdd', },
      stack: 'C',
      data: [ 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8 ]
    }, {
      name: 'A',
      type: 'line',
      areaStyle: { color: '#ffd' },
      stack: 'C',
      data: [ 2, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4 ]
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      type: 'line',
      areaStyle: { color: '#dfd' },
      stack: 'C',
      data: [ 2, 1.9, 2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1 ]
    }
  ],
  color: [ '#d34', '#fc1', '#3a4' ],
  grid: { left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 10, top: 40},
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.0.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 100%;height:180px;"></div>
```

After updating the ECharts version to the current release, hovering over the axis now fades the area colors, so they are almost not visible anymore.

I already tried different combinations of `silence: true` and `emphasis` settings and searched to online documentation, but I wasn't able to change the tooltip hover effect.

How can I disable the tooltip hover effect, so that the line and area colors are not changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [emphasis](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.emphasis) to override the highlight style of the graphic. See `itemStyle`, `lineStyle` and  `areaStyle`

```
  series: [ {
      name: 'C',
      type: 'line',
      areaStyle: { color: '#fdd', opacity: 1},
      stack: 'C',
      data: [ 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8 ],
      emphasis : {
        areaStyle: { //--> to avoid the fade effect, set the same color
          color: '#fdd'
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Other option is to change [silent](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.silent): true to disable triggering and responding to mouse events:

```
series: [{
      name: 'C',
      type: 'line',
      areaStyle: { color: '#fdd', opacity: 1},
      stack: 'C',
      data: [ 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8 ],
      silent: true //--> here
    }
  ...
]
```

Comment: Oh, nice and easy. I always tried to remove the emphasis entirely, which did not work. Using `silent: true` on all series also does not seem to work. But using equal emphasis and default colors does. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your welcome, Yes I think the first option is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the emphasis state completely, use [emphasis.disabled](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.emphasis.disabled) option:

```
options = {
  ...
  emphasis: {
    disabled: true,
  },
}
```